# Add Title and Artist to a DIV

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I'm trying to figure out how to get song title an artist into each ones div from this code. This code puts in the playlist all the songs from an XML file. My title div is songTitle and artist div is artists. Have tried copying whats in the getplayList function and removing the output, ul then putting in the onsongSelect function document.getElementById("songTitle").innerHTML = title; but I get only the last song title in the playlist in the div. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getplayList()
    {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        var elementsArray = xmlDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName    ('composition');
        var arrayLength = elementsArray.length;
        var output = "<ul>";

        for(var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            var title = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var artist = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('artist')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var time = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('time')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var fileName = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('filename')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;


            output +=  ("<li onclick='songSelect(\"" + fileName + "\")'>" + title + " -  " + artist + "</li>");


        }

            output += "</ul>";
            document.getElementById("playList").innerHTML = output;
    }
```

This is the songSelect function;

```
function songSelect(fn)
    {
        document.getElementById("songs").src = fn;
        playMusic();
    }
```

XML File only showed three songs there are more to long to post all:

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

xml +='<music>';
xml +='    <composition>';
xml +='    <title>Songs On The Radio</title>';
xml +='    <artist>No Justice</artist>';
xml +='    <time>4.24</time>';
xml +='    <filename>Songs On The Radio.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +=' <composition>';
xml +='    <title>Chillin It</title>';
xml +='    <artist>Cole Swindell</artist>';
xml +='    <time>3.17</time>';
xml +='    <filename>Chillin It.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +=' <composition>';
xml +='    <title>Tippin Point</title>';
xml +='    <artist>Dallas Smith</artist>';
xml +='    <time>2.58</time>';
xml +='    <filename>Tippin Point.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +='</music>';
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your xml file?

Comment: posted sample xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't close out the `ul` in your script assuming it is closed in your HTML. Commenting that out works.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/s7mLL/1/

**Update**

In which case you can change your `songSelect` method to accept an element parameter to get the clicked element, assuming your `div` has an ID of `nowPlaying`:

```
function songSelect(fn, element) {
    document.getElementById("songs").src = fn;
    playMusic();        
    document.getElementById("nowPlaying").innerHTML = "Now Playing: " + element.innerHTML
}
```

And make the following change in your for loop:

`output += ("<li onclick='songSelect(\"" + fileName + "\",this)'>" + title + " -  " + artist + "</li>");`

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s7mLL/2/

I might also suggest you star investigating [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It makes this kind of DOM manipulation much easier and gives you so much more.

**Further Update**

I wouldn't parse the XML twice. Change the method parameters to accept file name and title and pass those

```
function songSelect(fileName, songTitle) {
        document.getElementById("songs").src = fileName;
        playMusic();        
        document.getElementById("nowPlaying").innerHTML = "Now Playing: " + songTitle
    }
```

And make the following change in your for loop:

`output += ("<li onclick='songSelect(\"" + fileName + "\",\"" + title + "\")'>" + title + " -  " + artist + "</li>");`

http://jsfiddle.net/s7mLL/4/

**Bonus**

Here is a quick and dirty jQuery demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U88UQ/

Comment: I can get the Songs and Artists to show in the playlist. Trying to get the Artist and SongTilte in different div. onLoad and when I click on (li) in playList. Song plays when I click on each one in playlist fine.

Comment: Jon; I tried what you suggested Now what shows up in The songTitle div is Now Playing:--- Looking to get the Song Title Only in the songTitle  div from the XML file.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will have to check out jquery. Just learning javascript do see jquery seems like it has a lot more to it. All this is still a little confusing to me.

Comment: Yep, It's a good plan to get the basics of javascript before jumping into jQuery, you will get more out both of them this way. From what I've seen though, you are well on your way with javascript.